# neural network to train a image so as to get its unicode as output- python

Tags: python, pybrain

I have an image of a character. I wanted to make a neural network so that it takes the linear array of pixels as input and generate the Unicode of character so that i can compare it with the actual Unicode of that character. I tried it using pybrain but not able to write a code which can generate a Unicode. These are the parameters which i will be using for neural network:

• Learning rate = 150

• Sigmoid Slope = 0.026

• Weight bias = 30

• Number of Epochs = 300 ( Maximum)

• Mean error threshold value = 0.0002

I am thinking of following algo:

1. Form network according to the specified topology
   parameters
2. Initialize weights with random values within the
   specified ± weight bias value.[7]
3. load trainer set files (both input image and desired
   output text)
4. analyze input image and map all detected symbols
   into linear arrays
5. read desired output text from file and convert each
   character to a binary Unicode value to store
   separately
6. for each character :
   a. calculate the output of the feed forward
   network
   b. compare with the desired output
   corresponding to the symbol and compute
   error
   c. back propagate error across each link to
   adjust the weights
7. move to the next character and repeat step 6 until all
   characters are visited
8. compute the average error of all characters
9. repeat steps 6 and 8 until the specified number of
   epochs
   a. Is error threshold reached? If so abort
   iteration
   b. If not continue iteration

I am not able to generate unicode as output from neural network at step 6.
Please help

Comment: [what have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: i generated the pixels of my image and then created a network like this:

net = buildNetwork(154, 250, 16)

trainer = BackpropTrainer(net, ds, learningrate= 0.1, momentum = 0., )

trainer.trainEpochs(300)


should i take 'ds' as supervised training set? If yes then what should be the samples? Or should i go for unsupervised learning. In unsupervised learning how would i set the weight bias, sigmoid slope etc mentioned above?

Comment: What is your training data? Independently of whether you use supervised or unsupervised learning you will need lots of training data (images of unicode characters) for this. Also, when using unsupervised learning, your NN will only be able to tell apart characters, but not to tell which character an image shows.

Comment: My training data constitutes of an image of character and a text file in which that character is written. I am thinking of above mentioned algo(plz see in the question. i have edited it).